# Is it possible to set ClientAliveInterval from the client side?

Tags: ssh, sshd

Is it possible to set something like the sshd `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` from the client (ssh) side for a particular connection?

I am thinking of something like `ssh -o ClientAliveInterval=15` (which obviously doesn't work since -o is for client/ssh options. Or perhaps a way to have sshd options applied to particular connections.

My use case is that for remote port forwarding connections I would like to set the `ClientAliveInterval` low so that the server closes them more quickly. To goal being to avoid a stale sshd session holding on to the port and keeping me from reconnecting ("Error: remote port forwarding failed for listen port").

Note I am *not* looking for `ServerAliveInterval` or `ServerAliveCountMax` since they only control the client side of the connection, which doesn't help for remote port forwarding.

Comment: @pizdelect `ServerAlive*` settings matter when alive messages sent from the client cannot trigger response from the server. Maybe they get to the server and only the responses cannot get to the client. More likely the communication is disrupted in both directions. `ServerAlive*` settings will make the client consider the connection terminated, but how can it inform the server if packets cannot get to it in the first place? The server will consider the connection valid until `ClientAlive*` tell otherwise.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski indeed, maybe I was misinterpreting.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a separate connection *only* to forward port(s), i.e. possibly with `-N`, then consider this workaround:

```
while echo; do sleep 1; done | ssh user@server 'exec bash -c "while read -t 5; do :; done"'
```

(Include port forwarding(s) on your own).

When newlines from `echo` stop getting to the remote side, `read -t 5` will eventually fail and the entire remote loop will exit. The SSH server will notice its child process exited, it will terminate the connection and release the port(s).

Notes:

- `read -t` is not portable, the command explicitly calls `bash` to handle it.
- If the command interpreter for `user@server` is `bash` then there is no need for `exec bash`; sole `"while read -t 5; do :; done"` (instead of `'exec bash -c …'`) will work.
- `read -t 5` is quite straightforward. You can develop code that implements the concepts of `Interval` *and* `CountMax`.

I tested this approach on my laptop, with actual remote port forwarding (`-R`) and `beep` instead of `:` to hear from the server. When I disconnected Wi-Fi, the beeping stopped. When I reconnected Wi-Fi quickly, the beeping caught up and continued. But when I reconnected few seconds too late, the local command exited because it learned the SSH server had terminated the connection as designed. Important things:

- There were other SSH connections to the same server, governed by `*AliveInterval` and `*AliveCountMax`, and they survived. This means my special connection ended without assistance from these options. If I waited long enough with Wi-Fi turned off, then almost all connections would terminate because of the options, including the local half of the special connection. The exception would be the remote half; it would have been long gone anyway because `bash` would had exited.
- I was able to connect again *immediately*, never got `remote port forwarding failed for listen port`. Therefore I think my approach can be a valid solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible to control those settings from the client side.  They control how often the server sends keepalive messages and how many to wait for before disconnecting.  Those are server-wide settings and apply to all connections.  Allowing clients to set them, even per-connection, would have security implications since it could permit malicious clients to consume excessive server resources.

If you wanted to set those settings, you'd need to do that in the server's `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` file.  Note that setting them such that dropped connections are terminated quickly shouldn't be a problem, since generally those connections would be dropped eventually anyway.